# How to clear file input without lose event listeners and expanded properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I want to clear the file input in my form but I'm using AngularJS and other JQuery components and I can't lose the event listeners and expanded properties.

There is a way to do without removing or using JQuery `replaceWith` or `clone` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just setting it's `value` property to empty string?

```js
function clearFile() {
  document.getElementById("file").value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="" id="file" />
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="clearFile();" />
```

Comment: I think its enougth, need a little more tests using event handlers, expando and validadors, like required.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace file input with its clone ;

```js
$('#delImg').on('click', function() {
   $('body #exampleInputFile').replaceWith($('body #exampleInputFile').val('').clone(true));

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
  
<button type="button" id="delImg" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```